# Symfony2 - Many to many form with only certain elements

Tags: php, symfony

I have a *manyToMany* relationship between **players** and **coaches**. Each player can have many coaches and each coach can have many players.

The coach can create many teams if he wants. Throughout the process of creating a team, he has to select the players that will be part of his.

The coach can add in his team only players for which he has specific permission. This is an exterior process to the current problem but it demonstrates that not all the players in the database can be shown in the form but only the players for which he has permission to do so.

The players that must be shown are available via :

```
 $players = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getPlayers();
```

Now, when I display the form to create a team, here's what I'm doing:

```
$builder->add('players', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'OSCUserBundle:Player',
'property'     => 'name',
'multiple'     => true
```

));

This however, gives me all the players available in my database. Is there a way to specify symfony2 to show in the form only certain players ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [query_builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) paramter to query for only the players you want

So for example

```
    $builder->add('players', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'OSCUserBundle:Player',
    'property'     => 'name',
    'multiple'     => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQuery('SELECT p FROM YourBundle:Player p WHERE p.active = 1')
    },
```

Or if you already have the list of players you want you can use the [choices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices) option